# C++ Type casting order / Proper code-formatting?

Tags: c++, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Declaring pointers; asterisk on the left or right of the space between the type and name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660633/declaring-pointers-asterisk-on-the-left-or-right-of-the-space-between-the-type-a)
>   [what is the difference between const int*,  const int * const, int const *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const)

I've been wondering what is the difference between:

```
float const &var
const float &var
```

And which one of these is the correct way of writing the code? (including the above example):

```
float const& var
float const &var
float const & var
```

and with pointers:

```
float * var
float *var
float* var
```

I always put the special marks just before the variable name, feels most logical. Is that the correct way ?

Comment: It.  Doesn't.  Matter.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660633/declaring-pointers-asterisk-on-the-left-or-right-of-the-space-between-the-type-a Leads to more duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All are equally valid. There is no one correct way; you should do whichever you find most readable (for your own code) or follow the prevailing style (if working with others).

Putting `const` first (e.g., `const float &` rather than `float const &`) is more common in my experience.

The positioning of `&` and `*` depends on programmer; no choice seems more common than any other, in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question:
Refer this:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.8

> const X& x and X const& x are
>   equivalent.

When it comes to pointers:

```
float *var
```

is the best way.

The reason is that it doesn't give a wrong impression when you have multiple pointer variables.

For example:

```
float *var, *foo, *bar;
```

Is correct if you are wanting 3 pointer variables.

Compared to the possibly wrong code:

```
float* var, foo, bar;
```

Comment: I say stop pointing multiple declarations on the same line. Or know what you're doing if you do.

Comment: You can have your cake and eat it with `float* var,* foo,* bar;` :)

Comment: Well, we can have holy wars on personal preferences on coding style. It was just my take. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: _we can have holy wars on personal preferences..._  Not on Stack Overflow, we won't.

Answer (score 0):

The first code snippet you exposed reminds of the const correctness: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness#C.2B.2B_syntax. 
In the other two code snippets any of variants have the same effect.
For further information about pointers and the const keyword read also the following piece of documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/