# In objective-C what's the difference between Type* var, and Type *var?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, pointers

Oh the joys of being a memory management noob !

I'm getting bit by some Objective-C code, eventhough I understand the basics of pointers, I've seen these two different constructs, without being able to really understand their difference.

Can anyone enlighten me ?

Edited my question, the constructs didn't behave differently, instead I got bit yet again by the multiple declarations gotcha.
Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring pointers; asterisk on the left or right of the space between the type and name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660633/declaring-pointers-asterisk-on-the-left-or-right-of-the-space-between-the-type-a)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There’s no difference – it’s a matter of taste. However, beware that the pointer actually always binds to the name, not the type. So this:

```
Type* var1, var2;
```

Declares `var1` as a pointer to `Type`, while `var2` is *not* a pointer. That’s just one more reason not to declare multiple variables in the same statement.

Historically, the `Type *var` notation is more common in C, where it is read as “`var` is declared as a pointer to `Type`”, i.e. “the type of `*var` is `Type`”. In C++, on the other hand, `Type* var` is more common and is read as “`var` is declared as being of type ‘pointer to `Type`’”.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference at all.

But consider the following line:

```
Type* var1, var2;
```

Here only var1 is a pointer to Type, but it is easier to see that if you write

```
Type *var1, var2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it acts differently ? It seems a bit strange to me. Even if I don't know about Objective-c, in C there would be no difference between

```
Type* var
Type * var
Type *var
```

It's just a matter of syntax / preference.

Except if you're not talking about **declaring** a variable, but **access** it ?