# Difference in list declarations

Tags: c++, list, declaration

What is the difference between the following declarations?

```
list<int> myList;
list<int> *myList=new list<int>;
```

Is one declaration more suited for a particular example than the other or are they just different ways of saying the same thing?
Also what is the difference between the following declarations?

```
list<int> *myList=new list<int>;
list<int>* myList=new list<int>;
```

Is one of the above declarations wrong or they are same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use the new keyword in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655065/when-should-i-use-the-new-keyword-in-c)

Comment: To your second, unrelated question: [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2660643/645270). Do your research. I searched for _"asterisk space c++"_

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that the first statement is of value type, and the second of pointer type.

The first statement allocates the needed memory for a `list<int>` on your stack, the second statement allocates the memory needed for a pointer of type `list<int>*` on your stack and allocates and fills the needed memory for a list on the heap.

**EDIT:** To answer your second question:

```
list<int> *myList=new list<int>;
```

and

```
list<int>* myList=new list<int>;
```

are just different ways of stating the same thing. There are different arguments for and against playing the star next to the variable name or not.

Comment: How do you know it is not a global variable?