# is there a difference between char* a, char * a and char *a?

Tags: c

I am pretty new to c and I was review some code.
I came across this:

```
static char * fromDataType;
static char * toDataType;
static char * fromRank;
static char * toRank;
static char * fromMethod;
static char * toMethod;
static char * fromAction;
static char * toAction;
```

I was wondering if `char* a` and `char * a` and `char *a` the same?

Comment: They're identical.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660633/declaring-pointers-asterisk-on-the-left-or-right-of-the-space-between-the-type?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

White space is not significant in C source, except as a token separator.  Spaces are not always required to separate tokens.

In this particular case, *one space* is required somewhere in between `char` and `a` to separate them.  Any additional spaces are not semantically meaningful.

Comment: Well, not completely true. `a+++a` and `a+ ++a` mean different things.

Comment: Why is that _one space_ required? Isn't `char*a;` valid?

Comment: @mafso: Perhaps, but the spec is so opaque to me that I couldn't find the place that said that.  I've never actually seen it written that way.

Comment: @mafso I think Robert was referring to `char a` needs one space.

Comment: That is what I was referring to.  Not sure if the tokenizer considers `*` to be a valid replacement for that required space.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thought, there is another peculiarity of C I didn't know :). And yes, I haven't seen it either (and I assume most agree that this looks ugly). FYI, if understand the spec correctly (C11 6.4.6 and 6.7.6 p.1), it's allowed.

Answer (score 2):

They are just slightly different ways to write **EXACTLY** the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

char *a, char * a and char *a is same. 
But take the case of 
(i) char *a,b 
(ii) char * a,b 
In the second case it gives the impression that both a and b are of char pointers

Answer (score 0):

Although `char* a`, `char * a` and `char *a` (and, indeed, `char*a`) all mean the same thing, it may be possible to start a small religious war by suggesting that `char* a` is the one true way, and all others are abominations, heresy, unclean, etc.  Equally, since `char *a` was good enough for K&R, then all other forms betray `clue < 0` (as we say in Cucamonga).

Comment: `char *a` reflects how the grammar actually works; it's always parsed as `char (*a)`.  That is, the type of the *expression* `*a` is `char`.  I understand why some people write `char* a` (it emphasizes the type of the *object* `a`), but it leads to mistakes like writing `char* a, b` and believing both `a` and `b` are pointers.

Comment: @JohnBode: I could agree that following the grammer for types is clearer, if that grammer wasn't quite so ineffably obscure !  The obscurity of the grammer is self-evident, but I offer a small example: everyone knows `const char *a` (read from the back) "pointer to char which is constant".  But if you write `const char const *a` expecting "pointer which is constant to char which is constant", then you will be disappointed.  In fact, `char const* a`, "pointer to constant char", is closer to the grammer, and hence `char const* const a`, which *is* a "constant pointer to constant char" :-(