# Function changes data on other variables

Tags: c, linked-list, structure

i have structure Trip and i make linked list for this Trip, when i add trip to the list i dont have problem, but when add the second trip it overrides the first one.
The input I do is adding two trips with id 1 and 2 and when i iterate them i see there is two times id 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char date[10];
char date2[10];
char newdate[10];
char newdate2[10];
int i,t,i2,t2;
int ret;

int option;



typedef struct trip
{
    int code;
    char startdate[10];
    int duration;
    double price;
} Trip;

typedef struct list
{
    Trip* Trip;
    struct list* next;
} List;


List* create_List(Trip* trip)
{
    List* newList = malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (NULL != newList)
    {
        newList->Trip = trip;
        newList->next = NULL;
    }
    return newList;
}

void delete_List(List* oldList)
{
    if (NULL != oldList->next)
    {
        delete_List(oldList->next);
    }
    free(oldList);
}

List* add_List(List* wordList, Trip* trip)
{
    List* newList = create_List(trip);
    if (NULL != newList)
    {
        newList->next = wordList;
    }
    return newList;
}

void createTripData(Trip *trip);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    List* trips;
    int first = 1;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Select an option: \n 1-add new trip \n 2-Iterate\n");
        scanf("%d", &option);

        if (option == 1)
        {
            Trip newTrip;

            createTripData(&newTrip);

            if(first == 1)
            {
                first = -1;
                trips = create_List(&newTrip);
            }
            else
            {
                trips = add_List(trips, &newTrip);
            }
        }

        else if (option == 2)
        {
            system("@cls||clear");
            List* iter;
            for (iter = trips; NULL != iter; iter = iter->next)
            {
                printf("Id %d \n", iter->Trip->code);
            }
        }


    }
    return (0);
}

void createTripData(Trip *trip)
{
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Enter id: ");
            scanf("%d", &trip->code);//
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior on all but a very few implementations and is non-portable. Whenever a "Function changes data of other variables", that generally means you are writing beyond the bounds of a block of memory, happily smashing the memory of neighboring variables. Double-check your use of pointers and the dereferences you make. Avoid the use of *global variables* unless absolutely required -- none are required here.

Comment: Scope of `Trip newTrip;` is inside this if-block. Moreover, You use it repeatedly.

Comment: newTrip is just middleman who then add the trip into  List* trips

Comment: But it is limited in scope to within the `if` block`. Once you exit the `if` block, its memory address (which you have stored in `trips`) is released as "available for reuse" by the system (which of course is happening every iteration). So you likely end up storing the all values input at the same address and assign that address within `trips` which leaves you attempting to access a memory address that has gone out of scope outside the `if` statement and right off the cliff into *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: Additionally, you do not need `option` at all. Just initialize `List *trips = NULL;` (**note:** the `'*'` goes with the variable, not the `type`). Then all you need is a check `if (trips == NULL) {..create 1st node..} else {..add node to end..}`

Answer (score 1):

A problem with your code is the `newTrip` variable. You can **not** add it to the list the way you are trying. It is a **local** variable in a part of main. Therefore it goes out of scope (i.e. becomes invalid) when you exit that part of main. I'll suggest that you rewrite `createTripData` like:

```
Trip *trip createTripData()
{
    Trip* t = malloc(sizeof(*t));
    if (!t)
    {
        // Ups... add error handling
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Enter id: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &t->code) != 1)
    {
        // Ups... add error handling
        exit(1);
    }

    return t;
}
```

and call it like:

```
    if (option == 1)
    {
        Trip* newTrip = createTripData();

        if(first == 1)
        {
            first = -1;
            trips = create_List(newTrip);
        }
        else
        {
            trips = add_List(trips, newTrip);
        }
    }
```

Besides that you can simplify your code by handling the *empty list case* inside `add_List`.

```
List* trips = NULL;     // Notice this initialization

while(1)
{
    printf("Select an option: \n 1-add new trip \n 2-Iterate\n");
    scanf("%d", &option);

    if (option == 1)
    {
        Trip* newTrip = createTripData();
        trips = add_List(trips, &newTrip);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot,earlier i saw even when i scanf the new id changes the one in the list even when i dont use add_List

Comment: @HristoVutov - that was because you used the local variable. This answer allocates a new `Trip` each time and therefore it doesn't happen.

Comment: I know this is copy, but it is good practice to show `List *trips = NULL;` Especially when helping new C programmers, because in `int* a, b, c;` (`b` and `c` are certainly not pointers). Attaching the `'*'` to the `type` lends itself to confusion, `int *a, b, c;` is much less susceptible to misinterpretation.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - I just copied from OPs question. I didn't pay any attention to it. I don't think you'll find a common consensus. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2660648/4386427

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin IMO `List* trips = NULL;` is fine, and you should avoid writing `int * a, b, c;` regardless of positioning of the star

Comment: Differing opinions on the subject are fine. The `int *a, b, c;` is largely for example purposes, although I see no problem with it if for clarity if a `'\n'` follows each `comma`. Agreed, the compiler doesn't care either way, the issue, to me, is clarity and readability of what is declared as a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

the function: createTripData() calls `scanf()` but fails to check the returned value (not the parameter values) so if the user enters just a return key or enters anything but  digit(s) then the code accepts the nothing input,  This is an error

The function: `main()` has two parameters, but neither is being used. the function `main()` has two valid signatures:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
int main( void )
```

since the parameters are not used, the code should use the signature:

```
int main( void )
```

The function: `main()` is getting the menu selection from the user via:

```
scanf( "%d", &option );
```

but not checking the returned value (not the parameter values) so when the user only enters a 'return' or any character other than a digit, the prior value in the field `option` is used. if the user entered any digit besides 1 or 2 then the code 'screams' through the `while()` loop, doing either nothing or per what ever value was previously in the variable `option`.

I.E. ALWAYS check the returned value from calls to any of the `scanf()` family of functions and handle errors.

in the function: `main()`, a assumption is made that the user entered either 1 or 2.  That is NOT a valid assumption. (never trust the user to do the right thing) Strongly suggest the `if( option == 1` and `else if(option == 2)` be replaced with a `switch() statement that includes a`default` case for when the user enters any number other than 1 or 2 I.E.

```
switch( option )
{
    case 1:
        ...
        break;

    case 2:
        ...
        break;

    default:
        printf( "INVALID option: %d, valid options are 1, 2\n", option );
        break;
}
```

this field, in the definition of `struct list`

```
Trip* Trip;
```

It is very poor programming practice to name a variable the same as the type of the variable.  A possible fix:

```
Trip *myTrip;
```

Then update the other references in the code to use `myTrip`

It is very poor programming practice to name a variable the same as the type of the variable, with the only difference being the capitalization.  Such practice leads to confusion in the human reading the code.

In function: `create_list()` what happens when the call to `malloc()` fails?  A NULL pointer is returned to function: `add_List()` which returns that NULL pointer to function: `main()`, which (successful or not) overlays the value in the variable `trips`.

the statement:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

while being allowed in visual studio, is NOT portable. suggest using something like:

```
int ch;
while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch );
```

regarding the calls to `scanf()`, here is one way to handle the error events:

```
if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &trip->code ) )
{ // then error occurred as 'scanf' returns number of successful input/conversions
    perror( "scanf for code failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, scanf successful
```

The above suggested method immediately exits the program (leaving the OS to cleanup all the allocated memory, which would be poor programming practice)  You might want to, instead code a loop that informs the user of the problem, empties stdin and allowing the user to try again.

this statement:

```
printf("Select an option: \n 1-add new trip \n 2-Iterate\n");
```

will become very 'difficult' to read and understand if there are several choices in the menu.  suggest making use of the C feature of bring all the consecutive strings together and writing the statement like this:

```
printf("Select an option: \n"
       " 1-add new trip \n"
       " 2-Iterate\n");
```

Note: the suggested formatting also pays attention to the right edge of the printed page, making for a much nicer layout.

the function: `delete_List()` is never called, so the 'menu' in `main()` is missing an option.

BTW:  the function: `delete_List()` uses recursion, which is OK if the linked list is rather short.  However, if there are a lot of entries in the linked list then (especially on windows) there is a high probability of overflowing the stack.  I suggest using a loop to walk the linked list, passing each entry to `free()` after saving the `->next` pointer  Then it does not matter how many entries are in the linked list

for ease of readability and understanding: 
 1. separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do... while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line
 2. separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)
 3. follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Now, why are you seeing the problem you mention in the question:

the second pointer passed to `add_List()` is to a uninitialized local pointer on the stack in `main()`, not to the actual pointer to the linked list that was declared by: `List* trips;`

Suggest using unique names so YOU can keep track of what is pointing to what.

Also,in function: `create_List()`, the new node is being set to point to that uninitialized pointer in main(), rather than to the desired entry in `trips` in main.

Note, in function: `main()`, in modern C compilers, if the returned value is always 0, then the `return` statement is not needed.

Note: the statement `return` is not a function, so there is no need (unless wrapping multiple expression into a single result value) to have parens around the value passed back by `return`.

for simplification, suggest elimination of the variable `first`, changing `List* trips;` to `List *trips = NULL;` and replacing: `if(first == 1)` with: `if( !trips )`

I.E.  always try to write the simplest code that still performs the functionality.