# 'const Name &var' or 'const Name& var'?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What makes more sense - char* string or char *string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558474/what-makes-more-sense-char-string-or-char-string)

Sorry if this is a silly question, I am new to these things :-)

I am working on a C++ code base which uses the following reference conventions:

- const Name &var
- const Name& var

As far as I'm aware, they mean the same thing.

Which of these is either of these preferred, or mandated?

I don't like the ambiguity of having to choose one or the other.

The closest I have found to this answer is on http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Reference_Arguments , which uses the &var layout.

Comment: If you don't like making decisions about coding style, then you're not going to like c++ or any of the related languages(c,java,c#,etc...).  But if you're going to follow somebody's standards, Google is not a bad way to go.

Comment: I prefer `Type const& var` because it keeps the two modifiers of `Type` together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the language or compiler perspective both are exactly same. For a group project, you have to use a group style. For personal project, you are free to make any choice.

Though it is hard, but on topics like these, I always try to remember Rule# 0 from [C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, Best Practices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586):

> Don't sweat the small stuff. (Or: Know what not to standardize.)

If I have flexibility to choose, then personally, I always having prefer having spaces on either side of '*', '&', '=' etc. and so I write it as

```
const Name & var;
```

(Also, I never declare two variables in one line.)

Answer (score 2):

The two are equivalent.  The difference is purely one of style.

`const Name &var` is useful if you find yourself declaring multiple variables in a line:

```
const Name &var, foo, &bar;
```

Foo is a Name, but var and bar are references to a Name.

However, declaring multiple variables in one line is generally frowned on.

`const Name& var` makes it clearer that we're dealing with a reference type (since the reference symbol is located with the type name).

So, pick which style you prefer, and be consistent.  Using a consistent style is far more important than which style you use.

Answer (score 1):

As thyrgle says, if there is common style in use for a project or set of files, use that style. But if you're free to choose, then I think `T const& v;` is preferable. The `const` placement because that generalizes to more complicated declarations with more than one `const`, and the `&` placement because in C++ the focus is on types and because it makes less natural to try to declare two or more variables in one declaration. :-)

Cheers,

– Alf

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't care about whitespaces as long as you don't dabble in templates and operators, which seem to be a while away for you. In short, they mean the same thing, personally I prefer "const Name& var".

Comment: Actually, C++ does care a bit about whitespace inside and outside templates. Not a big difference actually. `a && b` is not the same as `a & &b`. `a >> b` is not the same as `a > >b`.

Comment: Ah, true. templates and operators then, thanks :) edited.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same for compiler.

Use the you like best one.

I prefer "const Name &var" because it looks better for two or more vars: "const Name &var, &var2, var3;" for example.

Answer (score 0):

C++ doesn't care about white spaces so each does exactly the same thing. But, you should use which ever one your company, or project host is using. For example: If I was working for Google I would use the &var layout because you need to keep everything consistent with what their style is.