# Correct C pointer notation

Tags: c++, c, pointers, coding-style

Which one is the best way to write:

```
string* str
```

Or:

```
string *str
```

Is there any drawback of side effect to one of them ?

Thanks

Comment: This is a style issue and you will get many different answers from many different people. It is not a question of correctness.

Comment: Many, many times duplicated. Searching now...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377164/whats-your-preferred-pointer-declaration-style-and-why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558474/what-makes-more-sense-char-string-or-char-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398395/in-c-why-is-the-asterisk-before-the-variable-name-rather-than-after-the-type etc...

Comment: I believe `string* str` is better, but I still voted to close since there is no "best" way.

Comment: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#whitespace

Comment: I disagree with you regarding the "subjective" argument, I wanted to know if there was any side effect to those notations. I got exactly the kind of answer I was looking for with the answer I accepted, see below.

Comment: I removed the subjectivity in my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Matthieu: It doesn't matter that you don't mean to spark an argument or that you phrase the question very carefully. This is one of those touchy subjects that is an argument waiting to happen. Like emacs-vs-vi or early subprogram exits or when is it OK to use a goto. You can't bring it up without a crowd gathering to watch the fight. The same thing goes for the proper positions in of the braces in c like languages. But I voted for "exact duplicate".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A reason to prefer the second one is when you declare multiple variables at once:

```
string *str, *foo;
string* str, foo;
```

Those two lines are different, the first one declares to pointers, whereas the second one declares one pointer to `string` and one `string`.

[Comment by FredOverflow] This problem can be solved by some template magic, though ;-)

```
template <typename T>
struct multiple
{
    typedef T variables;
};

multiple<string*>::variables str, foo;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly for those reasons that I asked the question !

Comment: Thank you FredOverflow for your edit.

Answer (score 3):

Although I prefer the first one there is a reason to prefer the second, consider:

```
string* str, a;
string *str, a;
```

In the last case it is clear that `*` applies only to `str`. However using such declarations is often considered a bad style.

Answer (score 3):

I do it like this:

```
string *str;
```

Because it makes a difference when you do this

```
string *str, *str2;
```

You could also do

```
typedef string* stringPtr;
```

So that you could do

```
stringPtr str, str2;
```

Comment: To the last one: No you didn't. *Didn't.*

Answer (score 2):

In C++ - neither - this should be `const string& str`.

Or is that `const string &str` ?  Hmm.

Comment: +1 for the "C++ is not C" answer

Comment: I often even write const string & str or int * pInt :-)

Comment: +1  I agree. In c++ there are rare cases when raw pointers are really needed.

Comment: I took a bad example with string... imagine this is a char and you'll see what i meant...