# Pointer on type instead of variable name?

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C, what is the correct syntax for declaring pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280729/in-c-what-is-the-correct-syntax-for-declaring-pointers)
>   [Correct C pointer notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071068/correct-c-pointer-notation)

What is the difference between

```
int* x
```

and

```
int *x
```

(if one exists) ?

Comment: That's great thanks! I'll accept one of the answers as soon as Stack Overflow allows me!

Comment: It's possibly a duplicate, but mine has a more specific name (for instance that question didn't appear when I did a quick search on the matter).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They both the same. Only difference is that you cant declare many variables in such way:

```
int* x, a, b; //a and b are not pointers

int *x, *a, *b; //all are pointers
```

I use first notation, for me it shows that variable has pointer type, not pointer itself.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. You will get in both cases an int pointer.

A reason to prefer the second one is when you declare multiple variables at once:

```
int *str, *foo;
int* str, foo;
```

Those two lines are different, the first one declares two pointers to int, whereas the second one declares one pointer to int and one int type variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same definition of pointer. both are pointer to an int

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace has no significance to the compiler in this case. But, some people might interpret it as meaning differently (as in what points to what). Not a good thing to do in my opinion (since whitespace is not something that should be taken into great account).

Answer (score 1):

there is no difference at all.

In both case these are pointers to `int`

`*` is associated with identifiers not the type

just for clear vision best practice to give space between `type` and `*`.

`int *p;`

for e.g. if you write

`int *p,q;` means `p` is a `pointer` but `q` is `int`. it signifies that * is associated with identifier name

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, but you just have to be careful when declaring multiple variables:

```
 int* x, y; // x is a int*, while y is just an int
 int *z, *w; // both z and w are int*
```