# Does the position of the * or & matters?

Tags: c++, pointers

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [In C, why is the asterisk before the variable name, rather than after the type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398395/in-c-why-is-the-asterisk-before-the-variable-name-rather-than-after-the-type)
>   [What's your preferred pointer declaration style, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377164/whats-your-preferred-pointer-declaration-style-and-why)

In C++, i see pointers put in different ways. for example,

```
char* ptr
char * ptr
char *ptr
```

Are the 3 examples above identical? (same goes with the &)

Comment: See also: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398395/in-c-why-is-the-asterisk-before-the-variable-name-rather-than-after-the-type), [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558474/what-makes-more-sense-char-string-or-char-string), [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660633/declaring-pointers-asterisk-on-the-left-or-right-of-the-space-between-the-type-a) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377164/whats-your-preferred-pointer-declaration-style-and-why)

Comment: syntactic and aesthetical sugar!

Answer (score 7):

Doesn't matter. (Eg. they are the same.) You could even write `char*ptr;` without any whitespace.
Beware though with multiple declarations on one line: `char* ptr, noptr;`. Here, the third syntax comes in clearer: `char *ptr, noptr;`.
My rule to avoid that confusion: Only one variable per line. Another way to do it right without the possibility to miss a `*`: `typedef` the pointer, eg:

```
typedef char* CharPtr;
CharPtr ptr1, ptr2; // now both are pointer
```

Though then you need to be aware of other things, like `const`ness, so I stick to my rule mentioned above:

```
typedef char* CharPtr;
const CharPtr p1; // const char* ?? or char* const ??
CharPtr const p2; // char* const ?? or const char* ??
// Eg.: Can't the pointer or the pointee be changed?
```

(And all of the above also applies to references `&`.)

Comment: hey yes the 3rd one is clearer..great thnx :)

Comment: +1 for `typedef char* CharPtr ;`

Answer (score 4):

C people tend to prefer `char *p`, whereas C++ people tend to prefer `char* p` (at least Bjarne does). The compiler could not care less about whitespace, you could just as well say `char * p` or `char*p`.

Many people say that `char* p` is dangerous because `char* p, q` is potentially confusing. That is correct in principle, but:

1. To increase readability, you should not declare multiple names in one declaration, anyway.
2. And more importantly, in C++, you should generally prefer RAII types over raw pointers.

Answer (score 3):

It does not matter. However, C++ people tend to prefer `char* ptr`, while C people prefer `char *ptr`. It's all a matter of personal preference.

However, note that `char* ptr, noptr` declares `ptr` as a pointer and `noptr` as a char value.

Comment: That's pretty subjective, I like `char* ptr` more.

Comment: @Xeo, it's of course a matter of personal preference as well, but most people I've talked to prefer it this way.

Comment: @geofftnz: this declares a pointer to char and a char. Is this what you wanted ?

Comment: I always heard that `char *ptr;` is the "C-way" while `char* ptr;` is the "C++-way" (even my book said that! `;)`).

Comment: @Xeo How do you feel about lines such as `char* ptr, val;`? I prefer `char* ptr`, but I end up doing `char* ptr; char val;` for multiple declarations.

Comment: @Alexandre typically it's not, that's what @geofftnz was pointing out.

Comment: @Alexandre: I think he wanted to hint that it doesn't declare two pointers.

Comment: @tJener: My rule: One variable per line, only multiple variables when they are exactly the same, eg. all pointers or all references or none of them.

Comment: 'char *ptr' stress that only ptr will be a pointer in case of multiple declarations.

Comment: @Xeo Ah, yes, I meant that to be a multiline. What about `typedef`ing pointer types?

Comment: @tJener: That's a possibility, but like I said in my answers, you have to be aware of `const`ness: `typedef char* CharPtr; const CharPtr p1; CharPtr const p2;` What are those now? ;)

Answer (score 3):

C++ people emphasize the types, and C people emphasize the usage.

So you see `char* x` in C++, it is because "the type of `x` is pointer-to-char". C++ has a strong type system on which the language rests. This is *not* the case in C.

In C, you declare variables according to what you want to do with them. When you see `char *x` in C, the thought process is "when you dereference x, you get a char". Another example:

```
char (*f)(int);
```

reads "when you dereference `f` and call it with a int, you get a char", ie. `f` is a pointer to a function which takes int and returns char.

Answer (score 2):

They all work. `char *ptr` is often advocated because it makes it clearer what is happening in this case:

`char *ptr, var;`

This declares a char pointer and a char.

Answer (score 0):

The potential whitespace surrounding the `*` and `&` modifiers in declaration have no effect on the compiled code.

Comment: grrr...thnx..stupid thing bugging me

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a **free-form** language. So, space doesn't really count in this case and all mean the same.

Comment: Yes. I like to write my code with either no (extra) white space. Or a "\n" wherever white space should be. Both make it interesting to read.