# The asterisk in Objective-C object instance declarations: by the Object or by the instance?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's your preferred pointer declaration style, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377164/whats-your-preferred-pointer-declaration-style-and-why)
>   [In C, why is the asterisk before the variable name, rather than after the type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398395/in-c-why-is-the-asterisk-before-the-variable-name-rather-than-after-the-type)
>   [What makes more sense - char* string or char *string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558474/what-makes-more-sense-char-string-or-char-string)

When declaring a new instance of an object in Objective-C, does it make any difference where you put the asterisk?

Is this just a matter of personal preference?

```
NSString* string = @"";
```

vs.

```
NSString *string = @"";
```

Comment: This has been asked *many* times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180401/c-asterisks-and-pointers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660633/declaring-pointers-asterisk-on-the-left-or-right-of-the-space-between-the-type-a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558474/what-makes-more-sense-char-string-or-char-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377164/whats-your-preferred-pointer-declaration-style-and-why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398395/in-c-why-is-the-asterisk-before-the-variable-name-rather-than-after-the-type to name a few

Comment: I believe this question is still important because it's likely to be found by Objective-C beginners who might not know to use the phrase "C pointer".

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield - Which do you prefer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't make a difference, but there are good reasons to put it in each place:

- It makes sense to put it near the class, because that makes it feel like a type: `NSString*`, a pointer to a string. Sensible.
- It makes sense to put it near the variable, because that's what's actually happening: `*` is dereference. When you dereference your pointer `string`, you get an `NSString`. `*string` is an `NSString`. Sensible.

You may want to go with the latter because that's the way the compiler is thinking, so: `NSString* oneString, anotherString` will not work, whereas `NSString *oneString, *anotherString` is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply a matter of preference.  Putting the * next to the type emphasizes that it's part of the type, i.e. "pointer to an NSString".  However, this is usually frowned upon, because it ignores the fact that the * associates with the nearest variable name, not the type name.  For instance, the following doesn't work:

```
NSString* a = @"string1", b = @"string2
```

This is because a is a pointer, but b is not.

Putting the * next to the variable name is, in my opinion, more of a C/C++ convention, because it emphasizes that the * and the variable name together act kind of like a variable.

Personally, I put a space on both sides of the *.

Another question that asked the same thing is here:

[Declaring pointers; asterisk on the left or right of the space between the type and name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660633/declaring-pointers-asterisk-on-the-left-or-right-of-the-space-between-the-type-a)

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt make the difference wher you put that pointer symbol. If you declare multiple objects in single line, you do it like NSString *str1, *str2. So its more appropriate to put that asterisk close to object. I prefer it close to object instance.