# Can't allocate a pointer to object of abstract type?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, abstract-class

For some reason, I'm not able to initialize a set of pointers to an abstract data type like so:

```
gkAnimation* run = NULL, walk = NULL, idle = NULL;
```

I'm getting an error saying:

```
jni/STEP3D_GK_Wrapper_JNI.cpp:283:34: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'gkAnimation'
```

I haven't had this issue happen before, and I don't think the class itself is doing anything special for this error to happen or that it would matter. I can post more code if it helps, but I'm pretty stumped here. Any ideas?

Comment: This question has to be a duplicate, right?

Comment: Tag: "self-outsmarting".

Comment: I'm not certain I see the error, but I'm going to go with "put all declarations on separate lines"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that this syntax:

```
gkAnimation* run = NULL, walk = NULL, idle = NULL;
```

Does not mean:

```
gkAnimation* run = NULL;
gkAnimation* walk = NULL;
gkAnimation* idle = NULL;
```

It means:

```
gkAnimation* run = NULL;
gkAnimation walk = NULL; /* invalid */
gkAnimation idle = NULL; /* invalid */
```

You need to explicitly define each item in the list as a pointer:

```
gkAnimation *run = NULL, *walk = NULL, *idle = NULL;
```

This is why many prefer the syntax style of placing the pointer next to the variable rather than next to the type.

Comment: ...and why many prefer the convention of declaring at most one variable per source line.

Comment: @Casey Im not a big fan either.

Comment: Thanks, I also found this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618282/c-declaring-multiple-object-pointers-on-one-line-causes-compiler-error