# Using multiple file pointers trying to open select files at a time in C..?

Tags: c, file, pointers

Okay, so this is a part of a larger project and it has turned into an over whelming mess. I have attached a few examples from the program.

What I am trying to do, is open a certain number of files to be read based off of the users input for a previous question.
The user needs to also give the path to the folder, and I have to append the string with the filenames, which I haven't done yet because I am unsure of how I want to do that. 
But that isn't the issue at the moment. 
My problem is is that all my file pointers are errors, and my compiler is also saying that I have mismatched values that I am trying to compare, which I am not really sure why I am having that problem. 
Do you guys see anything/ know why my code is not working?

I have also attached a screen shot from one of the compilers I have tried. 
(yes I tried different ones, because there have been times that I have had massive errors, and then I changed compilers and they went away)

```
int bpSensors;
  int hrSensors;
  int btSensors;

//values read passed to other functions
  char bp1_Val1[20], bp1_Val2[20], bp1_Val3[20], bp1_Line[100],
          bp2_Val1[20], bp2_Val2[20], bp2_Val3[20], bp2_Line[100],
          bp3_Val1[20], bp3_Val2[20], bp3_Val3[20], bp3_Line[100],
          bp4_Val1[20], bp4_Val2[20], bp4_Val3[20], bp4_Line[100],
          bp5_Val1[20], bp5_Val2[20], bp5_Val3[20], bp5_Line[100];

  char filepath[1000];

//file pointers
  FILE* fpBP1, fpBP2, fpBP3, fpBP4, fpBP5;

 printf("Enter the path to the file holding the data files:");

     fflush(stdin);
     scanf("%s", filepath);

     if (bpSensors == 1)
     {

        fpBP1 = fopen(filepath, "r");
        if (fpBP1 == NULL)

        {

           puts("ERROR OPENING FILES");

           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        else
        {
           while (!feof(fpBP1))
           {
              printf("\n\nREADING BP_1.txt...");
              fgets(bp1_Line, 100, fpBP1);
              sscanf(bp1_Line, "%s\t%s\t%s", bp1_Val1, bp1_Val2, bp1_Val3);
              printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", bp1_Val1, bp1_Val2, bp1_Val3);
           }

        }

     }// end BP Sensor = 1

     /////////////BP Sensors = 2//////////////////
        {
           if (bpSensors == 2)
           {
              //open file 1 &2
              fpBP1 = fopen(filepath, "r");
              fpBP2 = fopen(filepath, "r");

              //if they dont open, error shoots
              if (fpBP1 == NULL)

              {
                 puts("ERROR OPENING FILES");

                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
              }

              fpBP2 = fopen(filepath, "r");
              if (fpBP2 == NULL)

              {

                 puts("ERROR OPENING FILES");

                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
              }


              else
              {
                 while (!feof(fpBP1))
                 {
                    printf("\n\nREADING BP_1.txt...");
                    fgets(bp1_Line, 100, fpBP1);
                    sscanf(bp1_Line, "%s\t%s\t%s", bp1_Val1, bp1_Val2, bp1_Val3);
                    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", bp1_Val1, bp_Val2, bp_Val3);
                 }
                 while (!feof(fpBP2))
                 {
                    printf("\n\nREADING BP_2.txt...");
                    fgets(bp2_Line, 100, fpBP2);
                    sscanf(bp2_Line, "%s\t%s\t%s", bp2_Val1, bp2_Val2, bp2_Val3);
                    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", bp2_Val1, bp2_Val2, bp2_Val3);
                 }
              }
           }
        }// end BP = 2
     //////////////////BP Sensors = 3//////////////
        {
           if (bpSensors == 3)
           {
              //open file 1 -3
              fpBP1 = fopen(filepath, "r");
              fpBP2 = fopen(filepath, "r");
              fpBP3 = fopen(filepath, "r");

              //if they dont open, error shoots

              fpBP1 = fopen(filepath, "r");
              if (fpBP1 == NULL)

              {

                 puts("ERROR OPENING FILES");

                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
              }
              fpBP3 = fopen(filepath, "r");
              if (fpBP3 == NULL)

              {

                 puts("ERROR OPENING FILES");

                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
              }
              fpBP2 = fopen(filepath, "r");
              if (fpBP2 == NULL)

              {

                 puts("ERROR OPENING FILES");

                 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
              }


              //read both files
              //if there open. files 1 -3 are read and displayed
              else
              {
                 while (!feof(fpBP1))
                 {
                    printf("\n\nREADING BP_1.txt...");
                    fgets(bp1_Line, 100, fpBP1);
                    sscanf(bp1_Line, "%s\t%s\t%s", bp1_Val1, bp1_Val2, bp1_Val3);
                    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", bp1_Val1, bp_Val2, bp_Val3);
                 }
                 while (!feof(fpBP2))
                 {
                    printf("\n\nREADING BP_2.txt...");
                    fgets(bp2_Line, 100, fpBP2);
                    sscanf(bp2_Line, "%s\t%s\t%s", bp2_Val1, bp2_Val2, bp2_Val3);
                    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", bp2_Val1, bp2_Val2, bp2_Val3);

                 }
                 while (!feof(fpBP3))
                 {
                    printf("\n\nREADING BP_3.txt...");
                    fgets(bp3_Line, 100, fpBP3);
                    sscanf(bp3_Line, "%s\t%s\t%s", bp3_Val1, bp3_Val2, bp3_Val3);
                    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", bp3_Val1, bp3_Val2, bp3_Val3);

                 }
              }
           }
        }// end BP = 3
```

This code follows this pattern for about 800 lines.

Comment: At least related to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13618282/694576 if not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition are wrong, it defines `fpBP1` as a pointer to `FILE`, and all other 4 are objects of type `FILE`.

```
FILE* fpBP1, fpBP2, fpBP3, fpBP4, fpBP5;
```

You should use the following:

```
FILE *fpBP1, *fpBP2, *fpBP3, *fpBP4, *fpBP5;
```

Or better, you should just do:

```
FILE *fpBP1;
FILE *fpBP2;
FILE *fpBP3;
FILE *fpBP4;
FILE *fpBP5;
```

Comment: Can also use `typedef FILE* tFilePtr;`, and then declare `tFilePtr fpBP1, fpBP2, fpBP3, fpBP4, fpBP5;`.

Comment: @barakmanos why you should hide the type of a file pointer?

Comment: @terencehill: I said "can", not "should".

Comment: i did that and it fixed it, thank you!