# C++ for loop with multiple pointer initializers

Tags: c++

In the for loop below:

```
struct Block
{
    Block(int d) : data(d), next(nullptr) {}

    int data;
    Block* next;
};

Block* aList = new Block(1);
Block* bList = new Block(2);

for (Block* a = aList, *b = bList; a != nullptr; a = a->next, b = b->next)
    if (aList->data != bList->data)
        cout << "Difference found.\n";
```

I don't like putting the * before b, but of course it's needed to distinguish Block from Block*.  Is there another way to do this?  `for ((Block*) a, b...` isn't a go.

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but still really close to be a duplicate [Declaring multiple object pointers on one line causes compiler error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618282/declaring-multiple-object-pointers-on-one-line-causes-compiler-error)

Comment: Yes, that's a good point, and I have edited the question.

Comment: @TopologicalSort when you edit the question and change it, please do it in a separate section (or open a new one if it totally another - witch is not the case here), so answers that were relevant to the original question, will stay so...

Comment: @KorelK No, don't do that. We don't want a timeline of changes. We can see old revisions in the post's history. _Integrate updates into the flow of the post,_ as the OP has done here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to repeat the `*` then you could use `using` and create an alias `BlockPtr` which you use instead of `Block*`:

```
int main() {
  using BlockPtr = Block*;

  BlockPtr aList = new Block(1);
  BlockPtr bList = new Block(2);

  for (BlockPtr a = aList, b = bList; a != nullptr; a = a->next, b = b->next)
    if (aList->data != bList->data)
      cout << "Difference found.\n";
}
```

Or relay on `auto`:

```
int main() {

  auto aList = new Block(1);
  auto bList = new Block(2);

  for (auto a = aList, b = bList; a != nullptr; a = a->next, b = b->next)
    if (aList->data != bList->data)
      cout << "Difference found.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You might do it like this:

```
for (auto a = aList, b = bList; a != nullptr; a = a->next, b = b->next)
    if (aList->data != bList->data)
        cout << "Difference found.\n";
```

Comment: This is probably the best option as long as you want them all to be the same type.  +1.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the type hiding tbh, but `aList` and `bList` are lexically near so I guess it's okay

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use:

```
Block* a = aList, *b = bList
```

---

EDIT:

#### Option 1 - Using Boost

```
#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>
/*
    ...
*/
for (BOOST_TYPEOF_KEYWORD(Block*) a = aList, b = bList;...)
```

Another option is to create a single variable of the type you want, and use it's type to initialize other variables (similar to auto):

#### Option 2

```
Block* aList = new Block(1);
Block* bList = new Block(2);

for (decltype(aList) a = aList, b = bList; ...) ...
```

#### Option 3 - Using Boost

```
#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>
/*
    Like the first option
*/
for (BOOST_TYPEOF(aList) a = aList, b = bList;...) ...
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

When declaring pointers, the `*` belongs to the name, not the type.  That means you can make `b` a pointer like

```
for (Block *a = aList, *b = bList; a != nullptr; a = a->next, b = b->next)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to declare two pointers in an expression.

```
Block* a = aList, b = bList;
```

It happens to be part of a `for` loop, but just as

```
int * a, * b;
```

is two `int` pointers, you can use

```
Block* a = aList, * b = bList;
```

in your `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

What about just defining a [type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)?

```
using BlockPtr = Block*;

for (BlockPtr a = aList, b = bList; a != nullptr; a = a->next, b = b->next)
    if (aList->data != bList->data)
        cout << "Difference found.\n";
```