# How to declare members in structures using commas in c

Tags: c

I am writing a queue implementation program(in c) that has 2 node variables, front and rear. I declared them as follows,

```
struct queue
{
    NODE* front, rear;
    int size;
};
```

Upon compilation, I get the following error,

> error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘NODE’ {aka ‘struct node’} from type ‘void *’.

> queue->rear = NULL;

For some reason it identifies rear to be of *NODE* type instead of *NODE**

The code works fine when 'front' and 'rear' are declared separately as follows:

```
struct queue
{
    NODE* front;
    NODE* rear;
    int size;
};
```

**How do I declare multiple variables in a single line in a structure(in c)?**

Comment: Read your code carefully: in `NODE* front, rear;` what is the type of `rear`?

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618282/declaring-multiple-object-pointers-on-one-line-causes-compiler-error

Comment: Note that the asterisk applies to the thing at the right from it, not to the left of it. So you should read `Node * front` as `Node (*front)` instead of `(Node*) front`. For this reason I personally prefer a space between the type and the asterisk and many styleguides recommend to define only one variable on each line.

Comment: Congratulations, you have just found the main reason why you should never declare them on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

```
NODE* front, rear;
```

is equivalent of

```
NODE* front;
NODE rear;
```

So it's no surprise than doing `queue->rear = NULL;` is invalid.

The proper declaration is

```
NODE *front, *rear;
```

but I heavely suggest that you don't do multiple declaration in one line for the reason that you migth confuse what is a pointer or not (it's why you created this topic).

I suggest

```
NODE *front;
NODE *rear;
```