# What is the difference between using a single deference operator and double dereference operator over a variable?

Tags: c

I just have a basic idea about pointers. What is the difference between `int *v;` and `int **v;` and is there any difference between `int* v;` and `int *v;` Please do let me know.

Comment: You should really read an introductory C tutorial. The content of your question belies the statement "I just have a basic idea about pointers".

Comment: There's no difference between `int* a`, `int * a` and `int *a`. Then, when dereferencing a pointer, you may end up with another pointer, which you'll need to dereference in order to get the value it's pointing to (if any). This process may be repeated again and again, resulting in some nightmare like `*****a;` or `*********b`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What makes more sense - char\* string or char \*string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558474/what-makes-more-sense-char-string-or-char-string)

Answer (score 12):

The `*` in a variable declaration does not mean the same thing as `*` after the variable has been declared. In a declaration, the `*` states that the variable being declared is a pointer to a value of the type you are declaring. In your example,

```
int *v;
```

is a declaration of a pointer to an `int` value, while

```
int **v;
```

is a declaration of a pointer to a pointer to an `int` value.

However, later in your code after declaration, you could then call

```
*v
```

to dereference that pointer, and get the value that is stored at the memory location that the pointer points to.

There is no difference between `int* v` and `int *v` in a declaration, though it is more clear to use `int *v` when declaring multiple variables in the same line. In

```
int* v, u
```

`v` is a pointer to an `int` while `u` is just an `int`, which could be unclear from that declaration, while writing

```
int *v, u
```

ends up being slightly more clear about your intention (making `v` an `int` pointer and `u` just an `int`).